# fast multiplication of int8 arrays by scalars

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse, 8-bit

I wonder if there is a fast way of multiplying `int8` arrays, *i.e.*

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    z[i] = x * y[i];
```

I see that the [Intel intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) lists several SIMD instructions, such as `_mm_mulhi_epi16` and `_mm_mullo_epi16` that do something like this for `int16`. Is there something similar for `int8` that I'm missing?

Comment: You're not missing it, it really doesn't exist

Comment: For arbitrary constants, you can unpack to 16-bit elements.  For constants, you might be able to break it down into a shift and add or subtract.  (8-bit shifts by a constant can be emulated with `_mm_slli_epi32` and `_mm_and_si128` with an appropriate mask.)

Comment: If you wanted to horizontal-sum z[] when you're done, you can use `pmaddubsw` to do 8-bit multiply -> horizontally add pairs into 16-bit accumulators.  (But it's signed x unsigned so it's tricky to use unless you know one of your inputs is signed-positive.)

Comment: Well for what it's worth, compiling it with highest optimization on makes gcc and clang disassembly look like some manner of Klingon language. https://godbolt.org/z/saGWh8EnW. I would think twice before challenging that unholy mess with some manual optimization until I've done some serious benchmarking.

Comment: @Lundin: It's just unpacking to 16-bit elements (with zero extension since it's going to truncate again) for 2x `pmullw` => `pand` / `packuswb` (pack back to bytes, with truncation so the unsigned saturation doesn't do anything).  At least that's what I assume; that's a strategy that makes sense and is compatible with the instructions present.  Aki's answer gets the same work done but with more efficient unpacking and re-packing.  (clang's output in your link extra complicated because it's unrolling by 2 vectors.  `-fno-unroll-loops` is handy for identify the auto-vec strategy.)

Comment: But yes, clang is probably not *much* worse than the best manual strategy, and that may be good enough / not worth the effort of improving, especially if it still does a good job with AVX2 (where lane-crossing unpack would be worse if not using Aki's slicing strategy), or with ARM NEON.  i.e. tradeoff of dev time / maintainability vs. speedup relative to good auto-vectorization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking the input into low & hi, one can

```
__m128i const kff00ff00 = _mm_set1_epi32(0xff00ff00);
__m128i lo = _mm_mullo_epi16(y, x);
__m128i hi = _mm_mullo_epi16(_mm_and_si128(y, kff00ff00), x);
__m128i z = _mm_blendv_epi8(lo, hi, kff00ff00);
```

AFAIK, the high bits `YY` of the `YYyy|YYyy|YYyy|YYyy` multiplied by `00xx|00xx|00xx|00xx` do not interfere with the low 8 bits `??ll`, and likewise the product of `YY00|YY00` * `00xx|00xx` produces the correct 8 bit product at `HH00`. These two results at the correct alignment need to be blended.

`__m128i x = _mm_set1_epi16(scalar_x);`, and `__m128i y = _mm_loadu_si128(...);`

An alternative is to use `shufb` calculating `LutLo[y & 15] + LutHi[y >> 4]`, where unfortunately the shift must be also emulated by `_mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(y,4),_mm_set1_epi8(15))`.

Comment: Oh nice, good idea to split high/low within 16-bit elements, instead of unpack low/high, if you want to truncate instead of using `_mm_packus_epi16` (`packuswb`).  The `x` vector here is `_mm_set1_epi16(scalar_x)`, and `y` is a load from the array.  (Added that in an edit for future readers while fixing a typo)

Comment: Does this really work? I'm getting some odd results

Comment: The multiplication version would need to be unrolled by a factor of 3 I think, since the multiplication has a latency of 5. For the `shufb` approach unrolling by a factor of 2 should be sufficient for optimal throughput.

Comment: @harold: thanks, both of the multiplies need to be mullo, I was overengineering it first. I'll double check.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: the querent's use-case is for independent work.  Out-of-order exec can hide `pmullw` latency across iterations since it's not part of a loop-carried dep chain, so unrolling isn't critical.  Overall throughput, not latency, is the key factor for this.